# JQuery Mobile remove slide page transition

Tags: jquery, mobile, transition

I'm working on a Mobile friendly web site and every time a button gets pressed I have the slide effect transition... and I can't find a way to remove it.

I tried adding:

```
<script>
  $(document).bind("mobileinit", function() {
      $.mobile.page.prototype.options.addBackBtn = true;
      $.mobile.defaultPageTransition = 'none';
      $.mobile.useFastClick  = false;
});
</script>
```

and

```
 <a href="page.html" data-role="button" data-theme="f" data-transition="none">NEXT</a>
```

but I still have the slide effect transition.

How do I remove it?
Thanks!
Marco

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This is working for me:

```
$(document).bind('pageinit', function () {
    $.mobile.defaultPageTransition = 'none';
});
```

jQuery Version: 1.6.4 
jQuery Mobile version: 1.0.1

Live Example:
http://jsfiddle.net/jaf8P/